# How to use xamarin profiler integrated with visual studio for profiling the android app

Tags: android, xamarin, profiling

The xamarin profiler looks for an exe, but I cant find any exe that is generated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the profiler through a separated package that you can find at https://xamarin.com/profiler.

Comment: I have installed the standalone xamarin profiler. But it expects a *.mlpd file. How to create such a file.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked that and I think it is a bug. With version 0.16 you had to navigate to your debug folder. Once there you could choose between *.mlpd, *.exe or in my case an Android *.apk file.

To validate you answer I installed the latest version (version 0.18 by now) and I can not choose anymore.

So the only way to use the profiler on Windows seems to be creating an *.mlpd file. How you can do this is described in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125266/how-to-take-heap-snapshot-of-xamarin-androids-mono-vm).

Some additional readings I would like to suggest:

[Mono Log Profiler](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/debug+profile/profile/profiler/)

[Profiling iOS](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/monotouch_profiler/)

[Profiling Android](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/profiling/)